# Autocomplete Support Fragment issue : closes search bar during typing

Tags: android, google-places-api, android-cardview, autocompletetextview, google-places-autocomplete

I have been trying to apply Android Google Places Autocomplete feature using new Places SDK by below steps:

added dependency

```
implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
```

added permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

at xml file

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="4dp">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/autocomplete_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"                                 
     android:name="com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.AutocompleteSupportFragment"/>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

at my Activity file

```
// Initialize Places.
Places.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "My API KEY");

// Create a new Places client instance.
PlacesClient placesClient = Places.createClient(this);

// Initialize the AutocompleteSupportFragment.
AutocompleteSupportFragment autocompleteFragment = (AutocompleteSupportFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.autocomplete_fragment);

// Specify the types of place data to return.
autocompleteFragment.setPlaceFields(Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME));

// Set up a PlaceSelectionListener to handle the response.
autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
        // TODO: Get info about the selected place.
        //Log.i(TAG, "Place: " + place.getName() + ", " + place.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Status status) {
        // TODO: Handle the error.
        //Log.i(TAG, "An error occurred: " + status);
    }
});
```

Problem is while I am trying to type any key on search bar it close the search window.

Note : API key is enabled, and after enabling the API key I got same API which I already enable in this project for 'Maps SDK for Android'.

If anybody got the solution please provide.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This place picker method is already deprecated in 2019. please follow the latest one to implement the place picker here is the link   https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is there any way to do this without enabling billing option? I mean free implementation